# R as.date not working with NAs

Tags: r, date

I have two functions, to detect if a column in a df contains dates and then converting such column into timestamp.

However, the first function returns false for columns with some NA values, even if some values actually are dates. How can I fix?

```
is.Date <- function(date) {
    if (sapply(date, function(x) {
        !all(is.na(as.Date(
            as.character(x),
            format = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        )))
    })) {
        return(TRUE)        
    } else {
        return(FALSE)
    }      
}

fundate <- function(x) {      
    x <- x %>%
           mutate_if(
             is.Date,
             .funs = . %>%
               strptime(format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %>%
               as.POSIXct()
           )
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` will only check and use the first element, whereas it seems that you would like to use a vectorized version given the `sapply(date, ...`

You can fix it by getting rid of the outer `if / else` altogether, you are already producing TRUE and FALSE output with the `sapply`

---

edit following comment:

```
is.Date <- function(column) {
  !all(is.na(as.Date(
     as.character(column),
     format = c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M","%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  )))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However if I get rid of if it will return FALSE/TRUE for each value of the df, rather than for each column. Since I need to pass the Is.Date to MUTATE_IF, I need to reference the columns (TRUE if at least one of the values in the column is a date).

Comment: It would be easier if you could `dput` a data example, but let me edit with what I understand from your comment